# How to configure apache with domain name in raspberry pi

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, raspberry-pi, configure

i have a raspberry pi(IP: 192.168.1.135) connected to my PC(IP: 192.168.1.100) via LAN port.

PC is connected to a router(IP: 12.168.1.1).

i got raspberry to get connected to router, i bridged the lan and wlan port so (in windows7 -> network and sharing center -> change adapter settings)

i configured apache with domain name http://www.myownraspberrypi.com/ at default port 80

but if i call the domain name in my PC its responding with **This webpage is not available** dialogue

please help me to configure the setting

my another doubt is that, is there any stetting to be loaded with my dlink DSL-2730 router to map the ip address of raspberry pi with domain name(in router)?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> my another doubt is that, is there any stetting to be loaded with my dlink DSL-2730 router to map the ip address of raspberry pi with domain name(in router)?

Something like that, yes.

The problem is, just because your Apache claims to *accept* requests for `www.myownraspberrypi.com`, it doesn't automatically mean other computers will *send* requests to it. (Imagine, what would happen if you configured your Apache for `www.google.com`?) You still need to make that domain name actually point to your π's IP address.

The client computer (your PC) uses one of three ways to translate `www.myownraspberrypi.com` into an IP address:

1. the computer's own `/etc/hosts` file;
2. various LAN-only name discovery protocols;
3. Internet's DNS system.

If you only want to access the web server from one PC or two, you can add the name in their [`hosts` files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) by hand, like this:

```
192.168.1.135 www.myownraspberrypi.com
```

Some routers *do* have an option to make a domain name available to the entire LAN, although often limited to `hostname.home` or such. Look for a section called "Local DNS". (Though it *would* be much better to use `.home` than `.com` for this purpose.) But I don't think D-Link routers have that feature.